# Basic Binary Tree Program c++

Tags: c++

So I have been learning all about Binary Trees and decided to write a simple program to demonstrate to myself that I can implement my knowledge into working code. All I am trying to do with this code is add 4 numbers into a binary tree and output the numbers in order from least to greatest. Although, I did run into a problem with my code. When i run the code, Visual Studio breaks it at lines 29 and 59. I believe the problem has to do with the recursive function addLeaf but maybe its something else. Any advise, solutions, or input would be greatly appreciated.!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

node* root = NULL;

node* createLeaf(int data)
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->data = data;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;

    return n;
}
void addLeaf(int data)
{
    node* curr = root;


    //If tree is empty, create first node
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = createLeaf(data);

    }

    //Left(Less than)
    else if(data < curr->data)
    {
        //Check for curr->left
        if(curr->left != NULL)
        {
            addLeaf(data);
        }
        else //Adds node to left if null
        {
            curr->left = createLeaf(data);
        }
    }
    //Right(greater than)
    else if(data > curr->data)
    {
        //Check for curr->right
        if(curr->right != NULL)
        {
            addLeaf(data);
        }
        else //Adds node if right is Null
        {
            curr->right = createLeaf(data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The data " << data << " has already been received\n";
    }


}

void printTree(node* Ptr)
{


    if(root != NULL)
    {
        if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
            printTree(Ptr->left);
        }
        cout << Ptr->data << " ";
        if(Ptr->right != NULL)
        {
            printTree(Ptr->right);
        }
        cout << Ptr->data << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The Tree is empty\n";
    }


}

int main()
{
    int data[4] = {1, 7, 5, 4};
    node* Ptr = root;


    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        addLeaf(data[i]); 
    }

    printTree(Ptr);



    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you organize your tree in a class, instead of free functions and global variables?

Comment: Can you be specific on which line is line 29 and 59? no one is gonna count line by line for you

Comment: If you're curious: lines 29 and 59 are an empty line and an opening bracket. I don't think a debugger will break on those.

Comment: @roeland I am about to post the same comment too. lol

Comment: seems like the recursion never ends..

Comment: Your addLeaf function needs to also take a node pointer.  Otherwise, when you call it recursively, it hasn't traversed the tree - it's always stuck at the root.

Comment: you need to pass in head (root) to addleaf, and in subsequent calls to addLeaf, pass in curr->left or curr->right accordingly

Comment: Yes I realize now that lines 29 and 59 are not what I intentionally thought that they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `addleaf` function is going to run infinitely. You only keep adding to the root without any check.
You assign `Ptr` to `root`, but then using `new`, assign it to some new address in memory, which the root does not point to.
You have to pass `Ptr` by reference to `addLeaf`, otherwise changes will be made to its copy which is destroyed as `addLeaf` terminates.
`printTree` prints the current node value twice (a copy paste error?)

Here is the complete code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int data;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};

node* root = NULL;

node* createLeaf(int data)
{
  node* n = new node;
  n->data = data;
  n->left = NULL;
  n->right = NULL;

  return n;
}
void addLeaf(node* &curr, int data)
{
  //If tree is empty, create first node
  if(curr == NULL)
    {
      curr = createLeaf(data);
    }

  //Left(Less than)
  else if(data < curr->data)
    {
      addLeaf (curr->left, data);
    }
  //Right(greater than)
  else if(data > curr->data)
    {
      addLeaf(curr->right, data);
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "The data " << data << " has already been received\n";
    }
}

void printTree(node* Ptr)
{


  if(root != NULL)
    {
      if(Ptr->left != NULL)
        {
      printTree(Ptr->left);
        }
      cout << Ptr->data << " ";
      if(Ptr->right != NULL)
        {
      printTree(Ptr->right);
        }
    }
  else
    {
      cout << "The Tree is empty\n";
    }


}

int main()
{
  int data[4] = {1, 7, 5, 4};

  for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      addLeaf(root, data[i]);
    }

  printTree(root);

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one problem I can spot:

```
void addLeaf(int data)
{
    node* curr = root;
.....
        //Check for curr->left
        if(curr->left != NULL)
        {
            addLeaf(data);
        }
```

your so-called recursion did nothing.  It only keep on calling `addLeaf` function, and the function keep on checking if root's left is not null and in turn call the `addLeaf` again.

Refactor all your code. Don't use any global variable.  Make sure you passed correct parameters (e.g. you should pass the next level node to addLeaf)

Comment: another obvious problem to solve is, in `main()`, before you initialize your tree, you do `node* Ptr = root;`, then initialize your tree without ever touching `Ptr` again, and then `printTree(Ptr)`.  It will simply print the empty tree.